# Continuity of functions and composition

Tags: continuity

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$, $g:Y \rightarrow Z$ be functions such that

1)$f$ is onto,

2)$f$ and $g \circ f$ are continuous.

Under what minimal requirements $g$ is continuous?

I am only aware of Theorem 1 in [Kellum K.R.,  Rosen H. (1992). Compositions of continuous functions and connected functions.](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1992-115-01/S0002-9939-1992-1073528-7/S0002-9939-1992-1073528-7.pdf)

The topic is related to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3235529/is-composition-of-surjective-continuous-function-with-discontinuous-function-dis/3236659).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is also an open map, then for an open $U\subseteq Z$, we have 
$$g^{-1}(U)=f(f^{-1}(g^{-1}(U))) =f((g\circ f)^{-1}(U))$$
 is open. (The first equality holds because of surjectivity.)